# Nested Object Undefined After Mutation In Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

So I am looping through a list with v-for. Each object contains a nested object. Each list is filtered by a key. The `v-for` works great until I make an update which mutates the list. the `v-for` list looks like this

```
<tbody>
   <tr v-for="(engagement, index) in filteredEngagements" :key="index" v-if="engagement.workflow_id === selectedWorkflowID">
   <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" :value="engagement.id" v-model="checkedEngagements.engagements"></th>
   <th>{{ engagement.client.last_name}}, {{ engagement.client.first_name}} & {{ engagement.client.spouse_first_name}}</th>
   <td>{{ engagement.status }}</td>
   <td>{{ engagement.assigned_to }}</td>
   <td>{{ engagement.return_type }}</td>
   <td>{{ engagement.year }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

My trouble is with this line

```
<th>{{ engagement.client.last_name}}, {{ engagement.client.first_name}} & {{ engagement.client.spouse_first_name}}</th>
```

so the list is filtered by my computed `filteredEngagements` which uses a `getter` for  the data and `engagementFilterKey` for the correct key to filter by

```
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['allEngagements', 'users', 'allWorkflows']),
    filteredEngagements () {
      return this.allEngagements.filter((engagement) => engagement.status === this.engagementFilterKey)
      .filter( engagement => {
      return !this.searchEngagement || engagement.client.last_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchEngagement.toLowerCase()) >= 0 });
    },
  },
```

My mutation looks like this

```
updateCheckedEngagements(state, updatedEngagements = []) {
  const ids = updatedEngagements.map(engagement => engagement.id)
  state.engagements = state.engagements.map(engagement => {
  const matchedIndex = ids.indexOf(engagement.id)
   if(matchedIndex !== -1) {
    return{
      ...updatedEngagements[matchedIndex] 
    } 
   }
   return engagement
   })
  },
```

So once the list is updated by the mutation I cannot not filter the list by the key that I updated the list with, but if I refresh the page or simply click one of the other key options the filtered list still works fine.

Please view [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boldstar/u3mn89s0/) for example. **Note that the jsfiddle is set to mutate only 1 object at a time** however it does replicate the alarm I get on my set up. Again the issue is after I update the status of an object and then try to click on the status the object was updated to it will give me alarm saying that the property of the nested object is undefined...

Comment: Duplicate of your own question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120814/property-undefined-alarm-after-mutation-in-vue

Comment: @RoyJ, yes I figured it fell through the cracks so I tried rephrasing and reposting it...

Comment: It's just hard to tell what's going on. Probably your best bet is to try to make a simplified runnable example that exhibits the behavior.

Comment: @RoyJ, yeah I've been trying to recreate it on Jsfiddle but having issues there to. I can create the filtered list but haven't been able to get the mutation to work

Comment: @RoyJ, if your interested in what I have so far on my JSfiddle here it is [Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/boldstar/9j02rcd7/64/). I know its outside the scope of this question but if you can get the mutation working in the fiddle that would be awesome

Comment: How about you revise this question to point to the fiddle and explain what behavior you expect that you're not getting out of it? Is the idea that I could check a "received" item and have it updated to "completed"?

Comment: @RoyJ, yes you have the correct idea. And the issue of my original post comes in, if you click on the status the engagement is updated to. So for example you update "received" to "complete", if you then click on "complete" it would throw the alarm, however the other statuses would still work. I will revise my original post to point to the jsfiddle

Comment: I've updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9j02rcd7/95/). Note that the call to the commit needed to invoke `updateCheckedEngagements`, not pass the function itself, and I updated the `updateEngagements` function.

Comment: @RoyJ, So Im trying to implement your solution however my project is commiting `response data` from ajax request where as the example provided is commiting data directly to store mutation. I see that the discussion is getting long so if you'd like to chat please let me know